# Filter function deleting filtered words

Tags: html, jquery

I have this script, there are two portions. There is the filter portion and there is the highlight portion, both work great and as expected on their own. But when you combine them and type into the input field for example "this is" these words are eliminated as the filter function kicks in, the highlight function continues to work as normal. Can anyone help to explain this peculiar behaviour? I have tried the following, changing the keyup to keydown and alternating, changing the referencing names, changing the index values to no avail. This script's function is supposed to filter and highlight from one input field.Sorry about the parenthesis around code but my moblile does not have the code character.

I cannot post code from my mobile. Please see attached picture

Thanks[image]

Comment: Can't you wait until you get to your desktop so you can post code properly?

Comment: If you can't post the code then don't post anything. Create a [mcve], until then have a downvote

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with `.filter()`. The callback function is supposed to return a boolean to indicate which elements should be included in the result, but it's not returning anything.

Comment: And you're not doing anything with the result of `.filter()`. It seems like you should be using `.each()` instead of `.filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$("#search *")` to `$("#search > *")` or `$("#search").children()`.

I haven't looked at the hilitor code, but it presumably works by putting `<span></span>` around the highlighted portions, so that it can set their style. `#search *` matches descendants at any depth, not just the direct children of `#search`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar it was exactely what i needed. Damn you guys are smart.